# What is AdalDistributedTokenCache when using OpenID Connect in ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-ad-graph-api

The code shown here is my attempt to perform authentication in ASP.NET Core 2.0 against my Azure AD tenant.

The interesting part is my next set of objectives upon receiving an authentication code.

I want put the authenticated user's AD Groups into claims and have them passed along to my policy-based authorisation registrations.

To achieve this, I exchange the authorisation code for an access token.

Upon obtaining access token, I use Microsoft Graph SDK to retrieve the authenticated user's AD Groups.

Question 1: I have seen examples where the access token is stored in a cache `IDistributedCache`. Why is this important and what risk is there in not performing this step and what exactly is `AdalDistributedTokenCache`?

e.g.

```
   var cache = new AdalDistributedTokenCache(distributedCache, userId);

   var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ctx.Options.Authority, cache);
```

I find the access token is always at hand via

```
   string accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

Question 2: After retrieving groups, if I add these as claims to the Principal, can I then use them to drive authorization policies as described here?

[Policy-based authorisation in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies)

Question 3: Does the access token and id token along with the claims I add end up inside the cookie?

Question 4: How can I force Azure AD to return AD Roles as claims (not groups as I can get these via Graph) without having to change some kind of manifest?

Full code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            Configuration.GetSection("OpenIdConnect").Bind(options);
            options.SaveTokens = true;


            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async ctx =>
                {
                    // Exchange authorization code for access token
                    var request = ctx.HttpContext.Request;
                    var currentUri = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(request.Scheme, request.Host, request.PathBase, request.Path);
                    var credential = new ClientCredential(ctx.Options.ClientId, ctx.Options.ClientSecret);

                    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ctx.Options.Authority);

                    var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                        ctx.ProtocolMessage.Code, new Uri(currentUri), credential, ctx.Options.Resource);

                    // Use Microsoft Graph SDK to retrieve AD Groups
                    var email = ctx.Principal.Claims.First(f => f.Type == ClaimTypes.Upn).Value;

                    GraphServiceClient client = new GraphServiceClient(
                        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                        async requestMessage => {

                            var accessToken = result.AccessToken;

                            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                        }));

                    var groups = await client.Users[email].GetMemberGroups(false).Request()
                    .PostAsync();

                    // Do something with groups 

                    ctx.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
                }
            };
        });

        services.AddMvc()
                  .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
                  {
                      options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Index");
                  });
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to request access token again each time instead of caching and where would be the best place to do this? I ask because I am transferring from a project using IdentityServer that uses on-behalf flow and obtains new access token on each request.

Answer (score 5):

> Question 1: I have seen examples where the access token is stored in a cache `IDistributedCache`. Why is this important and what risk is there in not performing this step and what exactly is `AdalDistributedTokenCache`?

ADAL uses an in-memory token cache by default where it keeps the access and refresh tokens it acquires.
By using a distributed cache backed by e.g. Redis, all of the instances hosting the app can access the token cache.
This is required if the app runs behind a load balancer, and also prevents the data from being lost when the app restarts.

> Question 2: After retrieving groups, if I add these as claims to the Principal, can I then use them to drive authorization policies as described here?

You can add a new identity on the user principal, similar to my article: https://joonasw.net/view/adding-custom-claims-aspnet-core-2.
It *should* work if you add the identity in the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` handler.
They will be stored as claims using the default sign-in scheme, which is Cookies in your case.
So yes, you can use them in policies then.

> Question 3: Does the access token and id token along with the claims I add end up inside the cookie?

Yes, they are all persisted in the cookie.
However, you should use ADAL to get the access token when you need it.
The option to save tokens is not really needed in your case, as long as you set up the ADAL token cache correctly.

Acquiring the token: https://github.com/juunas11/aspnetcore2aadauth/blob/master/Core2AadAuth/Startup.cs#L75

Using a token: https://github.com/juunas11/aspnetcore2aadauth/blob/master/Core2AadAuth/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L89

The sample app first creates a token cache for the signed-in user.
Then, we use ADAL's `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` method to get an access token *silently*.
This means ADAL will return the cached access token, or if it has expired, uses the cached refresh token to get a new access token.
If both of those fail, an exception is thrown.
In the case of the sample app, there is an exception filter that catches the exception and redirects the user to login: https://github.com/juunas11/aspnetcore2aadauth/blob/master/Core2AadAuth/Filters/AdalTokenAcquisitionExceptionFilter.cs

> Question 4: How can I force Azure AD to return AD Roles as claims (not groups as I can get these via Graph) without having to change some kind of manifest?

If you mean roles like *Global Administrator*, you cannot get that in claims.
Roles which you define in the app manifest, and assign to users/groups are always included in the token. https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad

Comment: Still not sure why use the token cache if I could retrieve fresh access token each time? I ask because this is perhaps what I'd do when acquiring on-behalf tokens. What is so special about that particular access_token that I decide to cache?

Comment: I do not think you can get a new access token with an expired access token. You would need to use the refresh token for that. Keeping that in token cache allows you to get those new access tokens. The access tokens are cached to avoid unnecessary dependency calls.

Comment: Hmm, after thinking about your question more I see your point for APIs as you always have a fresh token from the caller. In that case the token cache just allows you to avoid that dependency call every time your API is called.

Comment: Though then you really need to use an in-memory cache as well, since otherwise you just swap one dependency call for another :D